# semaphore header not found on visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to use :

```
#include <semaphore>
```

on a a `cpp dynamic library` project created on `vs2017`.

The file is not found by the preprocessor. (mutex header is found..)

What am I missing?

Yigal.

Comment: Semaphores and the [`<semaphore>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/semaphore) header file are new from the C++20 standard. VS2017 isn't updated to support it.

Comment: [<mutex>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/mutex) header was introduced in c++ 11, while [<semaphore>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/semaphore) is availble since c++20. I think this is what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Standard library header `<semaphore>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/semaphore) was added in C++20. If you look at the [Compiler Support page for C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20), you can see that it is supported by MSVC from version 14.28/1928. [MSVC 14.28/1928 was introduced in Visual Studio 2019 v16.8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B), so older verions will not know the library.